# TYPO3 FlexForm <eval> message

Tags: typo3, eval, message, fluid, flexform

I have a FlexForm where i define an evaluation. What i would like to do is to show to the user a message on what went wrong. For example this is a piece of the FlexForm:

```
<gridRightDesktop>
   <TCEforms>
      <label>LLL:EXT:myExt/Resources/Private/Language/item.xlf:CustomGridRight</label>
        <config>
           <type>input</type>
           <size>2</size>
           <eval>num</eval>
           <range>
             <upper>12</upper>
           </range>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</gridRightDesktop>
```

Now, when the user's value is for example 13, an exclamation mark appears but no reason is described.

How can i get my own message to be displayed when the eval is triggered on the backend?

Comment: I suppose this is not what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215731/how-to-add-tooltips-to-a-flexform-plugin-configuration

Comment: It could be a start, but this extension that i am creating it is just to version my website. So it does not help that much. I now might now the way to do it according to your suggestion. We will see.

Comment: Else you still have the option to render the fields completely individual with a userfunction and then you can include everything you need.

Comment: would you mind to give an example?

Comment: What you first can try is to work with this, concerning your case it would require some creativity: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Columns/Index.html#displaycond

Comment: And the user function is explained here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/User.html

Comment: An example you find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558494/how-set-userfunc-parameters-in-typo3-flexform